# Module name "mysql" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])

Tags: javascript, mysql, ibm-cloud

I am new to javascript language.
I have created an application in Bluemix. To this application I have attached SQL database service. From the applications index.html, I am trying to call function "TryConnect()" which has the logic to connect to the SQL database.
Below is the implementation of TryConnect:

```
  this.TryConnect = function(){
        var mysql = require("mysql");
        var conn = mysql.createConnection({
            host: "127.0.0.1",
            user: "user",
            password: "password",
            database: "SQL Database-ox"
            });

        conn.connect(function(err){
            if(err){
                console.log("Error connecting to DB");
                return;
            }
            console.log("Connection Established");
        });
    }
```

upon running this I am getting below error:

Uncaught Error: Module name "mysql" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])

My index.html looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>NodeJS Starter Application</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/style.css">
    <script data-main="db" src="require.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="db.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function ConnectToMySQL(){
        alert("connect");
        TryConnect();
        alert("connect end");
    }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td style= "width:30%;">
          <img class = "newappIcon" src="images/Calendar.jpg">
        <td>
            <h1>Hello!</h1>
          <p>Welcome to Calendar sync application.
             This application synchronizes all your events, meetings and favourites.
    </table>

    <input type="button" onClick="ConnectToMySQL()" value="Connect to DB"/>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please remember, when posting code **redact all passwords and IP addresses**. Otherwise you're just asking for attention you don't need.

Answer (score 1):

> Module name "mysql" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])

Because on your code:

```
var mysql = require("mysql");
```

## Quick Fix

Do what the error asks you:

```
require(["mysql"],function(mysql){
       /// your code
});
```

## Long term

This and other things are discussed here : http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html

Recommend using `define` in the long term.

Comment: Thanks for the response, however, now I am getting error as : GET http://calendarsync.eu-gb.mybluemix.net/sqldb.js  & Uncaught Error: Script error for: sqldb
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror

Answer (score 0):

Please include node.js which will have "mysql" declaration so when you use require("mysql") javascript engine loads the deceleration from the given libraries.

Please refer to below links.

https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql

[MySQL requirements for examples](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/ndbapi/en/ndb-nodejs-examples-requirements.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your code, it worked for me :

```js
webPreferences: {
  nodeIntegration: true,
  contextIsolation: false
}
```

Comment: This appears to be for use in [electron](https://www.electronjs.org/blog/electron-4-0#webpreferences-default-values) apps and not directly related to the original question. If you experienced the error message described here under different circumstances you should for search a more appropriate question or post a new one and add this as an answer so that it may better help others searching for help in the future.